# Laravel method update with the logged user

Tags: php, laravel, sql-update

I have method store:

```
public function store(CreateProductRequest $request){
    $product = new Product($request->all());
    Auth::user()->products()->save($product);
    Session::flash('status3', 'Produkt został dodany poprawnie');
    return redirect('warehouse');
}
```

In this method I used `Auth::user` to add the name of the user who added a new record to the database.
I want to do the same in the method update:

```
public function update($id, CreateProductRequest $request){
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $products = new Product($request->all());
    Auth::user()->products()->update($products);
    Session::flash('status4', 'Produkt został zaktualizowany poprawnie');
    return redirect('warehouse');
}
```

and method products in model User:

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Product');
}
```

Laravel returned:

> Type error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::update() must be
>   of the type array, object given, called in ...

Answer (score 0):

change

```
Auth::user()->products()->update($products);
```

to this

```
Auth::user()->products()->update([
    'article_id' => $request->get('article_id'),
    'category_id' => $request->get('category_id'),
    'quantity' => $request->get('quantity'),
    'warranty' => $request->get('warranty')
]);
```

Comment: laravel returned error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '_method' in 'field list' (SQL: update `products` set `_method` = PATCH, `_token` = BMgunzjBgJKFBg1D1ubc5rxz5jGWLl4FRLQ7npRT, `article_id` = 2, `category_id` = 1, `quantity` = 3, `warranty` = 2016-07-08, `updated_at` = 2016-07-08 12:25:50 where `products`.`user_id` = 2 and `products`.`user_id` is not null)

Comment: you will have to go the long way around this. I'll edit my answer in a minute.

Comment: @major697 check it now

Comment: Laravel not returned error, but Laravel updates records, which is assigned to the logged-on user. Look [http://iv.pl/images/77973426415192398278.png](http://iv.pl/images/77973426415192398278.png)

Comment: that is because at the query that gets executed is the following `where` condition `products.user_id = 2`. it should be `where id = product_id`

Comment: So, how I can fix it ??